# Not able to connect Vertica Database through Python

Tags: java, python, jdbc, vertica, jpype

I am trying to connect to Vertica through Python using JayDeBeApi. But I am not able to establish a connection with the latest JDK(JDK 13.0.2) because it was not able to retrieve static attribute with Jpype(0.7.1).
Usually we used to connect to vertica through JDK5 and its Jar(6.3.1.0). And I couldnt find a link to download JDK5 anywhere. Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank in advance.

Comment: Please provide more details of the errore you get. Also notice that JDK5 can be downloaded form here https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-archive-javase5-downloads.html

Comment: AttributeError: '_jpype.PyJPField' object has no attribute 'getStaticAttribute'                                                     the above is the exact error I am getting

Comment: If there is no requirement for you to use JayDeBeApi, you should try vertica-python. It is the official python client for Vertica. It is maintained by Vertica, and there is no need for downloading JDBC drivers, etc.
- https://github.com/vertica/vertica-python